Property 'context' is missing in type '{}' but required in type 'IBreadcrumbsProps'
I have the breadcrumb declared in the component file and importing the class into another component file. But I started getting the error message
Property 'context' is missing in type '{}' but required in type 'IBreadcrumbsProps'.
I do not want to declare the context in the test1.tsx, as that will impact my another component.
Breadcrumb.tsx
import * as React from 'react';
import styles from '../NavigationEnApplicationCustomizer.module.scss';
//import { IBreadcrumbsProps } from './IGlobalNavProps';
import { SiteBreadcrumb } from "@pnp/spfx-controls-react/lib/SiteBreadcrumb";
import { FC, useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { ApplicationCustomizerContext } from '@microsoft/sp-application-base';

import { Breadcrumb, IBreadcrumbItem } from 'office-ui-fabric-react/lib/Breadcrumb'; 

export interface IBreadcrumbsProps {
  context: ApplicationCustomizerContext;
}

const HelloWorld: FC<IBreadcrumbsProps> = (props) => {

  return (
         <div className={ styles.helloWorld }>
            <SiteBreadcrumb 
            context={props.context as any} />
        </div>

);
};
export default  HelloWorld;

test1.tsx

